# Impersonation in Power Apps

Tags: powerbi, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-modeldriven

I have created app through PowerApps. This app is embedded with PowerBI reports and has role level security in PowerBI and PowerApps. One of my user is having an issue accessing app. I want to mimic his access to see issue or impersonate his account for debug. I don't have framework installed. How should I debug issue or impersonate access of the user to troubleshoot?

Thanks